# launch-navigator and Waze app - launch navigation rather than search results

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap-plugins, waze

I'm using `launch-navigator plugin` in ionic 3 project.
When I launch Waze app with an address, the app opens with search results with the address I passed.
also tried passing extra parameter `navigate:yes`

```
let options:LaunchNavigatorOptions = {extras: {navigate: "yes"}};
this._launchNavigator.navigate(to, options);
```

but not workign either.

Is it possible to open Waze app directly to the navigation screen with address I provided?

In Google Maps it is working just like that

Thanks

Comment: This is not the fault of the LaunchNavigator plugin: Waze always shows the address picker if input type is an address, even if `navigate=yes` is passed - [see here](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/issues/213)